# Using the word 'kind' for a category

Tags: nouns, word-usage

I found on [englishplus](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000231.htm) (accessed on 23 Dec 2012) that the phrase '***kind of animal***' refers to a category of animal.

> If you are using an expression like kind of, sort of, type of, or variety of, then you are putting the person or thing you describe into a category. Therefore, such expressions should not apply to one specific individual of the type.
>
> > Incorrect: He is the kind of leader we need.
> >      (You are referring to a specific person in the subject and to a category in the predicate.)
> >
> > Correct: He is like the kind of leader we need.
> >       (You are referring to a category, and he is an example of someone in the category.)

The confusion I have is that I feel now it is inappropriate to say “Spot is a kind of dog” (where Spot is a proper noun and the name of a certain dog). Instead, one should say “Spot belongs to a kind of dog” or “Spot is of a kind of dog”.  The idea that “Spot is a kind of dog” is incorrect follows from “He is like the kind of leader we need” being said correct by the above reference.

Then, I referred to the [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/kind). Its first sense for the noun form is:  “a group of people or things that are the same in some way...”.  To me it seems to validate the explanation at englishplus.com. But then it gives the following examples, among others:

> 1. The school is the first of its kind ...
> 2. They sell all kinds of things.

(1) seems to match with the theory that *kind* is a group.
(2) seems to suggest that *kind* is not a category but perhaps a common noun – since it is 'sell'able.

In the *kind of animal* phrase, I assume that *of animal* is a prepositional phrase acting as a qualifier of the noun *kind* used to select the kind required. Therefore to say that I am referring to a category of animals, I use the phrase *kind of animal* and then to show that *T* is an animal of this category, I say: “T is an animal of a {kind of animal}”  (ie, T is an animal of a kind of animal). Now, I have never come across such a sentence in my life. Please help me understand the source of the confusion and the correct usage of the word *kind*, whether as an idiom or by proper grammar.

Comment: Please edit question and include link to (or quote from) the  “dictionary whose respective definition matches with this theory” and its  “examples to the contrary”

Comment: I have edited this question from the earlier version, to add the actual references and quote the actual examples and descriptions, to correct ambiguties/mistakes in my earlier question, to give clarifications of the source of my confusion and to remove an information, accidentally introuduced and incorrect, by someone else's edit that I have referred to just one source (a dictionary). Some people have already answered to the previous version: http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/95217/revisions.

Comment: The quote from the englishplus.com webpage is nonsense, and sounds like it was written by a mathematician (or maybe a computer scientist who believes *all* languages should have strict type checking). Native speakers would say "He is the kind of leader we need" and never "He is like the kind of leader we need".

Comment: There is no reason to say _"Spot is a kind of dog."_  All _kinds of dogs_ are _dogs_ by definition.  You would say _"Spot is a dog."_.  You might say _"Spot is kind of a dog."_ which means that Spot isn't a dog, but has attributes that dogs have.

Answer (score 3):

*Kind* means *type*, among other things. Here's a chart of the [PIE root *ɡenə-](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/gen.pdf) (from which **all** senses of *kind* come, including the one that means *gentle*).

> (Note, parenthetically, that words for ruling classes develop good meanings in time, whereas words for commoners -- like *mean* and *common*, say -- don't.)

However, the fact that *kind* means *type* doesn't affect the grammar of the two words. Being *a kind* is a predicate, by itself, and *kind* (or, for that matter, *type*) should **not** be thought of as sets to which things *"belong"*. That's unnecessary complication.

There are idioms like *kind of* /'kayndə/ (*He's kind of shy*). *Type of* doesn't work here: **He's type of shy*. But they do both work in constructions like

- *What kind/type of idiot would do that?*

though *kind* is more idiomatic and *type* is more formal here.

Comment: I feel in my waters that you can't "belong" to a *type* or *kind*, but I can't see why that is so, given you can definitely [belong to a species](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22belong+to+a+species%22&oq=%22belong+to+a+species%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.5841&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Is it just that *kinds* and *types* aren't "formal category sets" that have ways of defining their *members*?

Comment: Not ISO ways, anyways. Quantifiers and qualifiers are always strange grammatically; they get used so often they're half-frozen into a lot of idioms and habitual frames. So succeeding generations get their own ideas about how they're organized, and language changes again.

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify/correct the source of my doubt. Please see the question again.

Comment: I think I see the problem. You are assuming that _of animal_ modifies a head noun _kind_, and therefore that _animal_ qualifies _kind_. That's backwards; it may once have had that structure, but nowadays _(a/the) kind of_ is the qualifier and it modifies _animal_, not the other way around. Like _gonna, wanna, hafta, useta_ and their ilk.

Comment: Thanks John. It's interesting to see this. In my school days I read a book called 'High School English Grammar and Composition' by Wren and Martin. And based on that book, I always considered that the preposition 'of' begins a prepostional phrase linking the noun 'animal' to the antecedent - 'kind'. Its enlightening to realize that 'kind of' has perhaps become an adjective now! I need to ask you another favour. It seems my grammar has gone out of date, therefore, can you please suggest me a good contemporary grammar book for a quick reading and another for a bit thorough reference.

Comment: For thorough reference, McCawley's _The Syntactic Phenomena of English_. For a quick reading, though, I really don't know anything I'd recommend. Almost everything taught in Anglophone schools about English grammar is either misleading, wrong, or downright bullshit, and nobody writes short books on grammar for any audience except students.

Answer (score 0):

The noun *kind* means simply *type*.  Per the OED, it can amongst other things mean:

- The character or quality derived from birth or native constitution; natural disposition, nature.
- Character as determining the class to which a thing belongs (cf. sense 13); generic or specific nature or quality; esp. in phr. *in kind*
- A race, or a natural group of animals or plants having a common origin

It is very closely related to the noun *kin*, and forms part of the word *mankind*.

Strangely, it appears to have no cognates in other languages outside of English.

Comment: My dictionary says "kin" is "akin to OHG chunni (race), Latin genus."

Comment: @gmcpath It is *kind* that has no apparent cognates outside English.

Comment: I think all OED and Etymonline mean is that this is there is no cognate which descends through a form suffixed *ge-* as *kind* does. But a step farther back and many Greek and Latin forms in *gen-*, *gon-*, *-gn-*, *germen-* (and of course their Romance descendants) are cognate, as well as such German words as *Kind* and *König*.

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify the source of my doubt. Please see the question again.